# What exactly does Adobe Enterprise and LiveCycle do?

Tags: networking, adobe

I've been reading here and there about Adobe Enterprise and LiveCycle, but I'm still basically clueless as to what their functions are and how companies would ultimately benefit from using these technologies. Any incite is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ultra quick version: business forms and automation related thereto. They are typically used to create data management systems. Call Adobe if that sounds interesting and they'll be glad to give you all the details.